# Loading images in Keras for CNN from directory but label in CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I have a set of image files in a directory `train_images = './data/images'`   and `train_labels = './data/labels.csv'`

For example - There are 1000 images in `train_images` as `377.jpg,17814.jpg ....` and so on. And the class they correspond to are saved in a different CSV file.

**EDIT**- Here are a few rows from the CSV file -

```
>>
    ID          Class

0   377.jpg     MIDDLE
1   17814.jpg   YOUNG
2   21283.jpg   MIDDLE
3   16496.jpg   YOUNG
4   4487.jpg    MIDDLE
```

Here I.D is the image file name and the class is the class it is associated to.

I could have used the very usual

```
ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_images, class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
```

but the problem is that labels are in a CSV file. What I could do is to rename all the files using `os` and put different files in different directories and then load it but it looks so immature and foolish.

How can I load data in Keras for CNN where each image is of dimension `(h,w,c)`?

Comment: post a few rows of the csv file

Comment: @abhilb sure. I've done it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my example using ImageDataGenerator, with the flow_from_dataframe function from ImageDataGenerator, and Pandas to read the CSV. The CSV I was using had two columns:

```
x_col="Image"
y_col="Id"
```

So the first column is the filename e.g. xxxx.jpg, and the second column is the class. In this case, since it is from the kaggle humpback whale challenge, what kind of whale it is. The image files are in the directory "../input/humpback-whale-identification/train/"

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, 
Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import 
ImageDataGenerator
from keras import regularizers, optimizers
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

So read the CSV using pandas:

```
traindf=pd.read_csv('../input/humpback-whale- 
identification/train.csv',dtype=str)
```

Now using ImageDataGenerator

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="../input/humpback-whale-identification/train/",
x_col="Image",
y_col="Id",
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(100,100))
```

Now sometimes the filename/ID in the CSV doesn't have an extension. So in that I used the following to add extensions to
them:

```
def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".jpg"

traindf["Image"]=traindf["Image"].apply(append_ext)
```

Well hope that is helpful! It's my first try at answering a Q here :-)

The Kaggle dataset/challenge is here https://www.kaggle.com/c/humpback-whale-identification

Note: I've seen people doing this in all kinds of ways on kaggle! But this seems the easiest!

Answer (score 3):

Then you can use `pandas` to read the `csv` file as a `DataFrame` using the function `read_csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csvfilename', delimiter=',')
```

---

Then use the `flow_from_dataframe` function of the `ImageDataGenerator` class.

There is a tutorial at this [link](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow-from-dataframe-8bd5776e45c1)

> flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, directory=None, x_col='filename', y_col='class', weight_col=None, target_size=(256, 256), color_mode='rgb', classes=None, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=None, save_to_dir=None, save_prefix='', save_format='png', subset=None, interpolation='nearest', validate_filenames=True)

Comment: No but Images are complete images and are stored together. These are only the labels and  class names which are stored in the CSV file. It means the image named 377.jpg belongs to class Middle.

Comment: I think I might have not been clear in forming my question.

Comment: thats ok. the labels will be read from the `column name` specified as the `y_col` argument.

Comment: it will associate the file name in the `x_col` with the class the in the `y_col`

Comment: No but images are not in dataframe. they are in a seperate directory. will work?

Comment: yes. `directory` path of the images directory. `x_col` - filename and `y_col` classname.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just worked. Had different sized imaged so setting the images  ```target_size=(None,None)```  a good call?