# Load image using csv (labels) for CNN?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I would like to know how am I able to load images with pandas and Keras Image data flow. Currently, my csv file contains

```
    ID               Category

0   1.png               1
1   2.png               2
2   3.png               1
3   4.png               2
4   5.png               2
```

and my file directory looks like this

```
 C:.
|   dataset.csv
|
+---test
|       10.png
|
\---train
    \---train
        +---01
        |       1.png
        |       3.png
        |
        \---02
                2.png
                4.png
                5.png
```

**However**, from the different StackOverflow solutions I have found, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464409/loading-images-in-keras-for-cnn-from-directory-but-label-in-csv-file) their train dataset is not sorted into their repsective category folder hence able to `flow_from_dataframe`.

> But in my case, my picture are further sorted into the different
> folders corresponding to the csv 'Category' which I am unsure how am I
> able to load the images using csv.

Is there a solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: You say `asddfasdsas.jpg`, `123123wqlwd.jpg` in the csv output. But in the second diagram you say `1.png`, `2.png`. Is that correct?

Comment: @thushv89 I have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your file directory structure, you do not need the CSV file to identify your image labels, and actually this is the folder TensorFlow(and most of neural network frameworks) expect you to have. The `flow_from_dataframe` method [is designed to resolve the problem without an expected directory structure](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c). To load your dataset, simply use `flow_from_directory` method. You may read [TensorFlow Official Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators) and [TensorFlow Document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) for more examples.